# Get variable value from a function to other function javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to get value from a function to another function . but i am new at javascript, can someone hlep me solve thi. i want to call the value of dinoRight, dinoLeft, and the other to cactus1move function.

```
const spawn = () => {
    const dinoRight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left + document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const dinoLeft = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left; 
    const dinoHeight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const cactusTop = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const cactusWidth = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const containerLeft = document.getElementById('Container').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    cactus1move();
}
const cactus1move = setInterval(()=>{
    if (cactusTop<=dinoBottom&&dinoRight>=cactusLeft&&cactusRight>=dinoLeft) {
        ...
    } else if (cactusLeft<=containerLeft+10&&cactusLeft>=containerLeft){
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
},20)
```

Comment: Define the cactus1move function in the spawn function, then vaviables of spawn are avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
const spawn = () => {
    const dinoRight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left + document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const dinoLeft = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left; 
    const dinoHeight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const cactusTop = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const cactusWidth = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const containerLeft = document.getElementById('Container').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    cactus1move(dinoRight, dinoLeft);
}


//not sure if you can pass it directly to the interval
    const cactus1move = setInterval((dino_right, dino_left)=>{
        if (cactusTop<=dinoBottom&&dinoRight>=cactusLeft&&cactusRight>=dinoLeft) {
            ...
        } else if (cactusLeft<=containerLeft+10&&cactusLeft>=containerLeft){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    },20)


//if it does not work you can pass the parameters to a function and then down to the interval
    const cactus2move = (dino_right, dino_left)=> {
        setInterval((dino_right, dino_left)=>{
        if (cactusTop<=dinoBottom&&dinoRight>=cactusLeft&&cactusRight>=dinoLeft) {
            ...
        } else if (cactusLeft<=containerLeft+10&&cactusLeft>=containerLeft){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    },20)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, variables are declared inside the functions (i.e the scope of these variables is restricted to function).
You can declare these variables outside the functions so that both the functions will have access to it.
Your code will go something like:

```
    let dinoRight, dinoLeft, dinoHeight, cactusTop, cactusWidth, containerLeft;
const spawn = () => {
        dinoRight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left + document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().width;
        dinoLeft = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left; 
        dinoHeight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        cactusTop = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().top;
        cactusWidth = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().width;
        containerLeft = document.getElementById('Container').getBoundingClientRect().left;
        cactus1move();
    }
    const cactus1move = setInterval(()=>{
        if (cactusTop<=dinoBottom&&dinoRight>=cactusLeft&&cactusRight>=dinoLeft) {
            ...
        } else if (cactusLeft<=containerLeft+10&&cactusLeft>=containerLeft){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    },20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters when calling the method, so that it can be used inside the method. If it is not necessary, I recommend not to use global variables to get the value.

In the following code, I call `cactus1move` passing the value and wrap the value into an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). When implemented inside `cactus1move`, I use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the value out of the object, and then you can use these values to do something.

```js
const spawn = () => {
  const dinoRight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left + document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const dinoLeft = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const dinoHeight = document.getElementById('dino').getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const cactusTop = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const cactusWidth = document.getElementById('cactus').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const containerLeft = document.getElementById('Container').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  cactus1move({
    dinoRight,
    dinoLeft,
    dinoHeight,
    cactusTop,
    cactusWidth,
    containerLeft
  });
}

const cactus1move = (data) => {
  return setInterval(() => {
    const {
      dinoRight,
      dinoLeft,
      dinoHeight,
      cactusTop,
      cactusWidth,
      containerLeft
    } = data;
    console.log('dinoRight', dinoRight);
    console.log('dinoLeft', dinoLeft);
    console.log('dinoHeight', dinoHeight);
    console.log('cactusTop', cactusTop);
    console.log('cactusWidth', cactusWidth);
    console.log('containerLeft', containerLeft);
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#dino {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFBB73;
  float: left;
}

#cactus {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #FFBB33;
  float: left;
}

#Container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFBB13;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='dino'></div>
<div id='cactus'></div>
<div id='Container'></div>
<button onclick="spawn()">spawn</button>
```